# IF statement in a PHP file to detect when there aren't any entries

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a job application form returning a person's details among other things.

Right now, these are returned on separate lines. And if there are no entries in any field, there is a blank line in the email that is sent.

I'd like to make an `IF` statement so that if there is no entry in any field, it will return "Not Applicable" in the mail.

example:

```
$nrel1 = $_POST['nrel1'];
$nrel11_name = $_POST['nrel1_name'];
$nrel1_age = $_POST['nrel1_age'];
$nrel1_gender = $_POST['nrel1_gender'];
$nrel1_education = $_POST['nrel1_education'];
$nrel2_employment = $_POST['nrel2_employment'];
```

Now if the applicant makes no entry in the `$nrel1_age` field, I want it to return "Not Applicable" in the mail.

Comment: No entry in ALL field or just ONE?

Comment: then you got your answer by @John Kugelman

Comment: edit to fix the confusing last sentence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function valueOrNotApplicable($array, $key)
{
    if (isset($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key]))
        return $array[$key];
    else
        return 'Not Applicable';
}

$nrel1            = valueOrNotApplicable($_POST, 'nrel1');
$nrel11_name      = valueOrNotApplicable($_POST, 'nrel1_name');
$nrel1_age        = valueOrNotApplicable($_POST, 'nrel1_age');
$nrel1_gender     = valueOrNotApplicable($_POST, 'nrel1_gender');
$nrel1_education  = valueOrNotApplicable($_POST, 'nrel1_education');
$nrel2_employment = valueOrNotApplicable($_POST, 'nrel2_employment');
```

It's good to check both `isset()` and `!empty()`. If you don't check for `isset()` then you may get "PHP Notice: Undefined index" warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nrel1_age = empty($_POST['nrel1_age']) ? 'Not Applicable' : $_POST['nrel1_age'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $nrel1 = (!empty(trim($nrel1_age))) ? $_POST['nrel1'] : "Not applicable";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($nrel1_age) && (trim($nrel1_age)!=''))
   return "Not applicable";
```

That should do the trick. Cheers

**EDIT**

Forgot the trim part.

Comment: if this is sent from a html form, the variable will always be set... but empty

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot tthe trim part

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional operator as below

```
$nrel1_age = isset($_POST['nrel1_age']) && trim($_POST['nrel1_age'])!=''?$_POST['nrel1_age']:'Not Available';
```